# X ignores xrdb merges

Tags: x11, xrdb

Installing snapd on fedora seems to have had a weird effect on the X installation and I need advice on how to debug it.  System is Fedora 36 and I have FVWM on X.  Until today on login `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc-common` would find my `~/.Xresources` file and load (technically -merge) it.  After the install this file is ignored.  The system-wide `/etc/X11/Xresources` *is* getting loaded on login, but the local one isn't.  For example, putting my personal settings in the global file has the desired effect.

Manually calling `$ xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` from a terminal does nothing, while `$ xrdb -load ~/.Xresources` clears the database but doesn't load anything (`$ xrdb -q` now has no output). `$ xrdb -load /etc/X11/Xresources` has the same effect (even though at login the file is loaded).  Running the commands as root has no effect either.  I am at a loss: how does one debug the interaction between xrdb and the X server?

Comment: have you found the root cause or solution?